# Chaining with array of promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I am making an ajax call to get an array of results. From that array I am making a series of ajax calls and am trying to do something with the results. When I return `Promise.all()` and proceed with `.then(function(moreData){})`, `moreData` is in pending state. I am missing something? I did not expect the function to run before every `doSomethingElse` function was resolved.

```
doSomething()
    .then(function(data){
        data = data.d.results;

        return Promise.all(data.map(function(group){
            return doSomethingElse(group.Id);
        }));                
    })
    .then(function(moreData){
            //moreData is in pending state
    })
    .then(null, function(err){
        alert(err);
    });
```

The `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse` functions return a deferred object.

```
function doSomething(){
    var dfd = $.ajax({...})
    return dfd;
}
function doSomethingElse(id){
    var dfd = $.ajax({...})
    return dfd;
}
```

Comment: is `moreData` an array?

Comment: Yes, I expected it to be. I get `Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}` instead.

Comment: What version of jQuery? i'm thinking this is going to be a conflict between jQuery promise implementation and whatever `Promise` is.

Comment: jQuery verions is 1.11.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your promise(s) are based on jQuery, use jQuery's version of `all`, [`.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/), but that requires some extra code:

```
doSomething()
.then(function(data){
    data = data.d.results;

    var results = new Array(data.length); // Array to hold the results of doSomethingElse
    return $.when.apply($, data.map(function(group, i){
        // Attach a done handler to async operation, put result in results array and return
        return doSomethingElse(group.Id).done(function(x) { results[i] = x; });
    }).unshift($.Deferred().resolve(results)); /* unshift a resolved deferred so that
                                                  moreData recieve results */
})
.then(function(moreData){
    // moreData is now and array with the resolved results of doSomethingElse()
})
.then(null, function(err){
    alert(err);
});
```

Comment: Careful, `$.when` expects Deferreds as arguments, not an array of Deferreds. Passing it an array causes it to resolve immediately with that array as the value. You'll want `$.when.apply($, ...)`.

Comment: I was trying not to use .apply() because then with a dynamic array I have to use arguments[] keyword. I've used `Promise.all()`, but am only successful when I do not chain it.

Comment: @MickB, I don't follow. Using `apply` is just to get your mapped array into `$.when` in the format jQuery expects it. I've made the edit to Amit's answer, so you can see what I mean. Everything else remains the same, where would you have to use `arguments`?

Comment: When I use `apply` and try to access the array of results in `.then()`, `moreData` only contains the first parameter `arguments[0]` and not the entire array of results.

Comment: @MickB Ah, I get you. Yep that's the way jQuery Deferreds work. A perhaps preferable alternative then is to convert the jQuery Deferred to a spec-compliant (e.g. ES6) Promise at an earlier stage. You'd do that by wrapping any jQuery Deferreds (such as the result of a `$.ajax` call within `doSomething`/`doSomethingElse`, for example): `properPromise = Promise.resolve(myjQueryDfd)`. The result of that will be a Promises/A+ compliant Promise which you can then use in the code in your question, including the `Promise.all()` call, exactly as is.

Comment: @Shai Ok, so I'm not as crazy as I thought I was. I'll give that a try. Thank you!

Comment: @MickB - look at the modified solution